# How to add NLog target Azure Event Hub, app settings

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, nlog, azure-eventhub

I want to connect Azure Event hub using NLog.Extensions.AzureEventHub because its part of  Nlog configuration, But not sure how do I pass the target correctly I am getting error but cant understand reason because I am passing the string , I check the online Nlog documentation but its only providing the Xml settings.    Could you please give example app settings for Nlog Azure Eventhub taget (C# .net core 6.0)

[NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage](https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureEventHub/README.md)

This is my app settings

```
  "NLog":{
"internalLogLevel":"Info",
"internalLogFile":"c:\\temp\\internal-nlog.txt",
"extensions": [
  { "assembly": "NLog.Extensions.Logging" },
  { "assembly": "NLog.Web.AspNetCore" },
  { "assembly": "NLog.Extensions.AzureEventHub" }
],
"targets": {
  "allfile": {
    "type": "File",
    "fileName": "c:\\temp\\nlog-all-${shortdate}.log",
    "layout": "${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
  },
  "ownFile-web": {
    "type": "File",
    "fileName": "c:\\temp\\nlog-own-${shortdate}.log",
    "layout": "${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}"
  },

  "eh": {
    "type": "AzureEventHub",
    "credentials": {
      "name": "eventhub1",
      "connectionString": "Endpoint=sb://eventhubnp198007.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=4z/JbjHp7UqxCWPD343434343GZbJpfG5E="
    },
    "layout": "${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}"
  }

},
"rules":[
    {
        "logger":"*",
        "minLevel":"Trace",
        "writeTo":"allfile"
    },
    {
        "logger":"Microsoft.*",
        "maxLevel":"Info",
        "final":"true"
    },
    {
        "logger":"*",
        "minLevel":"Trace",
        "writeTo":"ownFile-web"
    }
]
```

}

Error

```
> 2022-08-23 12:59:10.0781 Error AzureEventHub(Name=eh): Failed to
> create EventHubClient with connectionString= to EventHubName=.
> Exception: System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be an empty string.
> (Parameter 'connectionString')    at
> Azure.Core.Argument.AssertNotNullOrEmpty(String value, String name)   
> at
> Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Producer.EventHubProducerClient..ctor(String
> connectionString, String eventHubName, EventHubProducerClientOptions
> clientOptions)    at
> NLog.Targets.EventHubTarget.EventHubService.Connect(String
> connectionString, String eventHubName, String serviceUri, String
> tenantIdentity, String resourceIdentity, String clientIdentity)    at
> NLog.Targets.EventHubTarget.InitializeTarget()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have added the `"credentials"`-section, but I think it will work if you just remove it. Since it also doesn't exist in the [xml-config](https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureEventHub/README.md):

```json
  "eh": {
    "type": "AzureEventHub",
    "eventHubName": "eventhub1",
    "connectionString": "Endpoint=sb://eventhubnp198007.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=4z/JbjHp7UqxCWPD343434343GZbJpfG5E=",
    "layout": "${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}"
  }
```

The Json-configuration tries to map 1-to-1 with the Xml-configuration. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json

The only place where Json and Xml really divert is when handling "list of items". Where Json must specify the actual collection-name, and Xml supports node-items.

It is a good idea to use `"throwConfigExceptions": true` as it will quickly reveal invalid configuration. Especially when using NLog v5.

Btw. if you want the target `"eh"` to be used, then you must include it in the `"writeTo":`. Ex:

```json
{
    "logger":"*",
    "minLevel":"Trace",
    "writeTo":"eh, ownFile-web"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, That's getting better. now its showing this message "Warn Unused target detected. Add a rule for this target to the configuration. TargetName" How can I test ?How can I send a event log with nlog from c#?

Comment: @sansalk Updated my answer about include the NLog target `"eh"` in the `"writeTo"`-option for the Logging-Rule. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial